# Density property in Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like to ask if there is any clear (in details) proof of the fact that if the dimension $ N \geq 2 $ and  $ 1 < p < + \infty, $ then the space $ C_0^{\infty}( \mathbb{R}^N \setminus{
0}) $ is dense in the Sobolev space $ W^{1,p}( \mathbb{R}^N). $ \

Remark: I found some answers to similar questions talking about truncature near zero and $ \infty, $  but I cannot see exactly the sequence that approximates any function $ u \in W^{1,p}( \mathbb{R}^N). $

Thanks in advance.